# SharePoint Apps Getting the GUID of App-Provisioned List using JavaScript and CSOM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin

I'm a Sharepoint App beginner. I have a SharePoint 2013 App that provisions List. How can I get the GUID of those list using CSOM and JavaScript?

Here's what I got so far:

```
    var lists;

    function getLists()
    {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web, "Title", "Description");
        lists = web.get_lists();
        context.load(lists, "Include(Id, Title, Hidden, ItemCount)");
        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
    }

    function onSuccess() {
        var ul = $("#listsList");
        var listsEnum = lists.getEnumerator();
        while (listsEnum.moveNext())
        {
            var list = listsEnum.get_current();
            if (list.get_hidden() == false )
            {                    
                var title = list.get_title();
                var elem = $("<li>" + title + " with GUID " + list.id  + "</li>");
                ul.append(elem); // append the details to a list
            }
        }
    }

    function onFail() {
        alert("Request failed");
    }
```

The `list.id` is always undefined. How do I access the GUID property, or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `list.get_id().toString();` instead of `list.id`